# How to get values after dictionary sorting by values with linq

Tags: linq, dictionary, sorting

I've a dictionary, which i sorted by value with linq, how can i get those sorted value from the sorted result i get

that's what i did so far

```
Dictionary<char, int> lettersAcurr = new Dictionary<char, int>();//sort by int value
var sortedDict = (from entry in lettersAcurr orderby entry.Value descending select entry);
```

during the debug i can see that sortedDic has a KeyValuePar, but i cant accesses to it

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sortedDict is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char, int>>` iterate it

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over it.

```
foreach (var kv in sortedDict)
{
     var value = kv.Value;
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the `char` values you could modify your query as:

```
var sortedDict = (from entry in lettersAcurr orderby entry.Value descending select entry.Key);
```

which will give you a result of `IEnumerable<char>`

If you want it in a dictionary again you might be tempted to

```
var q = (from entry in lettersAcurr orderby entry.Value descending select entry.Key).ToDictionary(x => x);
```

but do bare in mind that the dictionary will **not** be sorted, since the `Dictionary(Of T)` will not maintain the sorted order.